# Rotary encoder for a candy box not working

Tags: c++, time, arduino, lcd

I have written this code for a time controlled candy box. The time and day when it opens will be controlled in a menu with a rotary encoder, two buttons and an LCD display. When pressing the switch button the menu opens. It starts with Monday and trough scrolling you can skip to Tuesday and so on. After Sunday a time menu should open. There you can choose on and off time. The days can be yes(1) or no(0).

Unfortunately I can't get the rotary encoder to work.
I hope somebody can help.
Regards.

````
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

//button Pins
#define B 8 // Button to unlock
#define L  5 //Lock/ Relay
#define B1 6 //Button for yes/ and unlock
#define B2 7 //Button for no
#define PUSHP 4 //SW to enter menu
#define PINA 3
#define PINB 2


//Led
#define LR 10 //Led Pin for Red
#define LG 11 //Led Pin for green

//integers to safe yes(1) or no(0)

int Monday = 1;
int Tuesday = 1;
int Wednesday = 1;
int Thursday = 1;
int Friday = 1;
int Saturday = 1;
int Sunday = 1;

char Weekday = Monday;

int onTime = 1;
int offTime = 24;

uint8_t B1val = digitalRead(B1);
uint8_t B2val = digitalRead(B2);
uint8_t SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);
uint8_t Bval = digitalRead(B);

int counter = 0;
int aState;
int aLastState;

volatile boolean turned;   // rotary was turned
volatile boolean fired;    // knob was pushed
volatile boolean up;  // true when turned cw

void isr ()
{
  if (digitalRead (PINA))
    up = digitalRead (PINB);
  else
    up = !digitalRead (PINB);
  turned = true;
}  // end of isr

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setSyncProvider(RTC.get);
  aLastState = digitalRead(PINA);
  //set pinmodes

  pinMode (PINA, INPUT);
  pinMode (PINB, INPUT);
  pinMode (B, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PUSHP, LOW);
  pinMode(B1, INPUT);
  pinMode(B2, INPUT);
  pinMode(PUSHP, INPUT);
  // Turn on the backlight and print a message.

}

void loop() {
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  Serial.println(Weekday);
  uint8_t Bval = digitalRead(B);
  uint8_t B1val = digitalRead(B1);
  uint8_t B2val = digitalRead(B2);
  uint8_t SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);
  tmElements_t tm;
  printDay();
  isr();
  delay(10);
  Serial.print(B1val);
  Serial.print(B2val);
  Serial.print(SWval);
  if (hour() >= onTime && hour() <= offTime) {
    analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50
    Serial.println("green");
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(L, LOW);
    analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50

  }

  if (Bval == 1) { //trying to unlock
    Serial.println("unlock");
    if (hour() >= onTime && hour() <= offTime  && 'Weekday' == 1) { //flash green led
      digitalWrite(L, HIGH); //unlock Lock
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LG, HIGH); //turn green Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
    }
    else { //flash red led
      Serial.println("unlock false");
      digitalWrite(L, LOW); //lock locked
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LR, HIGH); //turn red Led on
      delay(200);
      analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50 to not hurt your eyes
    }
  }
  if (hour() >= onTime && hour() <= offTime) {
    Serial.println("unlocked");
    analogWrite(LG, 50); //set light to 50
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("locked");
    analogWrite(LR, 50); //set light to 50
  }
  if (SWval == 1) { //to enter menu when rotary encoder switch clicked
    menu();
  }
  else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.noBacklight(); // turn off backlight
  }
}
void menu() {

  Serial.println("menu");
Monday:
  Serial.println("Monday");
  lcd.backlight(); //turn on lcd
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.print("     Monday"); //display print Monday
  while (1 == 1) {
    Serial.println("while");
    aState = digitalRead(PINA);
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);
    Serial.print(B1val);
    Serial.print(B2val);
    Serial.print(SWval);
    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1val == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Monday yes");
    Monday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Monday;
  }
  else if (B2val == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Monday no");
    Monday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Monday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Tuesday;

    else
      goto Monday;
  }

  delay(100);
Tuesday:
  Serial.println("Tuesday");

  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("    Tuesday"); //display print Tuesday
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Tuesday yes");
    Tuesday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Tuesday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Tuesday no");
    Tuesday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Tuesday;
  }

  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Wednesday;

    else

      goto Tuesday;
  }

  delay(100);
Wednesday:
  Serial.println("Wednesday");

  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("   Wednesday"); //display print
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Wednesday yes");
    Wednesday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Wednesday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Wednesday no");

    Wednesday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Wednesday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Thursday;

    else
      aLastState = aState;
    goto Wednesday;
  }

  delay(100);
Thursday:
  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("    Thursday"); //display print
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Thursday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Friday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Thursday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Thursday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Friday;

    else
      aLastState = aState;
    goto Thursday;
  }

  delay(100);
Friday:
  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("     Friday"); //display print
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Friday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Friday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Friday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Friday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Saturday;

    else
      aLastState = aState;
    goto Friday;

  }
  delay(100);
Saturday:
  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("    Saturday"); //display print
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Saturday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Saturday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Saturday = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Saturday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Sunday;

    else
      aLastState = aState;
    goto Saturday;

  }
  delay(100);
Sunday:
  aLastState = aState;
  aState = digitalRead(PINA);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("     Sunday"); //display print
  while (1 == 1) {
    B1val = digitalRead(B1);
    B2val = digitalRead(B2);
    SWval = digitalRead(PUSHP);

    if (B1val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (B2val == 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (SWval == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (B1 == HIGH) {
    Sunday = 1;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("      Yes  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Sunday;
  }
  else if (B2 == HIGH) {
    Sunday = 0;

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    lcd.print("      No  ");
    delay(100);
    goto Sunday;
  }
  if (turned)
  {
    if (up)
      goto Time;

    else
      aLastState = aState;
    goto Saturday;

  }

Time:
  Serial.println("time");

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("turn on:  "); //display print
  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  lcd.print(onTime);
  lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
  lcd.print(":00");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1); //set cursor
  lcd.print("turn off: ");
  lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
  lcd.print(offTime);
  lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
  lcd.print(":00");

OnTime:
  while (B1 != HIGH) { //accept on time
    if (B2 == HIGH) {
      while (B2 == HIGH) {}
      goto OffTime;
    }

    if (turned)
    {
      if (up)
        onTime + 1;
      else
        onTime - 1;
      aLastState = aState;
    }
    if ( onTime < 0) {
      onTime = 24;
    }
    if ( onTime > 24) {
      onTime = 0;
    }
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcd.print(onTime);
    lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
    lcd.print(":00");
    //   lcd.setCursor(9, 1); //set cursor
    //   lcd.print(offTime);
    //   lcd.print(":00");

  }



OffTime:

  while (B2 != HIGH) { //accept off time
    if (B1 == HIGH) {
      while (B1 == HIGH) {}
      goto OnTime;
    }

    if (turned)
    {
      if (up) {
        offTime + 1;
        Serial.println(offTime);
      }
      else {
        offTime - 1;
      }
    }
    if ( offTime > 24) {
      offTime = 0;
    }
    if ( offTime < 0) {
      offTime = 24;
    }
    //      lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
    //   lcd.print(onTime);
    //   lcd.print(":00");

    lcd.setCursor(9, 1); //set cursor
    lcd.print(offTime);
    lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
    lcd.print(":00");
    delay(100);
    if (B1val == 1) {
      loop();
    }

  }

}




void printDay()
{
  int day;
  day = weekday();
  if (day == 1) {
    Weekday = Sunday;
  }
  if (day == 2) {
    Weekday = Monday;
  }
  if (day == 3) {
    Weekday = Tuesday;
  }
  if (day == 4) {
    Weekday = Wednesday;
  }
  if (day == 5) {
    Weekday = Thursday;
  }
  if (day == 6) {
    Weekday = Friday;
  }
  if (day == 7) {
    Weekday = Saturday;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Is this on an arduino or similar? maybe the pinout would be useful as well to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of encoder (with electronic on a pcb) or a barebone encoder the ports may be different BUT
working with encoders means working with interrupts AND getting rid of all delay() in your loop and routines. 
Here is a test code for a rotary encoder which works 100% on an UNO:

```
    /* This code is without the push button function
    These pins can not be changed 2/3 are special pins -> Interrupt */
    const uint8_t encoderPin1 = 2;
    const uint8_t  encoderPin2 = 3;

    volatile int lastEncoded = 0;
    volatile long encoderValue = 0;
    long lastencoderValue = 0;
    uint8_t lastMSB = 0;
    uint8_t lastLSB = 0;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin (9600);

      pinMode(encoderPin1, INPUT);
      pinMode(encoderPin2, INPUT);

      digitalWrite(encoderPin1, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
      digitalWrite(encoderPin2, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
      /* Call updateEncoder() when any high/low changed seen
      on interrupt 0 (pin 2), or interrupt 1 (pin 3)*/
      attachInterrupt(0, updateEncoder, CHANGE);
      attachInterrupt(1, updateEncoder, CHANGE);
    }

    void loop() {
      //Do stuff here
      Serial.println(encoderValue);
      delay(1000); //just here to slow down the output, and show it will work even during a delay
    }

    void updateEncoder() {
      int MSB = digitalRead(encoderPin1); //MSB = most significant bit
      int LSB = digitalRead(encoderPin2); //LSB = least significant bit
      int encoded = (MSB << 1) | LSB; //converting the 2 pin value to single number
      int sum = (lastEncoded << 2) | encoded; //adding it to the previous encoded value
      if (sum == 0b1101 || sum == 0b0100 || sum == 0b0010 || sum == 0b1011) encoderValue ++;
      if (sum == 0b1110 || sum == 0b0111 || sum == 0b0001 || sum == 0b1000) encoderValue --;
      lastEncoded = encoded; //store this value for next time
    }
```

Try it (as you use also the 2/3 pin) and if it works integrate it into your code.
 Replace isr() with the functions of the test programm
If it does not work we have a HW issue, then a circuit and the make of the encoder might be helpful.